# This simple If statement send me an SyntaxError: invalid syntax on Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, error-handling

```
elephant_weight = 3000
ant_weight = 0.1

If elephant_weight > ant_weight:
 square()
```

And the error I get is:

```
 File "c:/Users/AIRWEBDEV/Documents/exercice.py", line 37
    If elephant_weight > ant_weight:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Python is case sensitive. Use `if` instead of `If`.

Comment: It also doesn't look like you have the right amount of indentation in the following line

Answer (score 2):

The right syntax is (note the `if` in lower case):

```
if elephant_weight > ant_weight:
    square()
```